# ASP.NET yellow screen of death - where does it get the stack trace from?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, targetinvocationexception, ysod

I have a remoting-type set up within  my application where I avoid `TargetInvocationExceptions` and grab the inner exception. I invoke the internal `PrepForRemoting` method on the `Exception` class to preserve the stack trace from the invoked method.

This appears to construct the stack trace property correctly:

> "\r\nServer stack trace: \r\n
>
> at ZBooking.Environment.Services.BookingService.<>c_*DisplayClass9`1.b*_5(BookingSlot p) in 
>   C:\dev\ZBookings\core\ZZBookings.Services\BookingService.cs:line 79\r\n
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.All[TSource](IEnumerable'1 source, Func'2 predicate)\r\n
>
> at ZBookings.BookingService.MoveBooking[TBookingType](Int32 bookingId, >IEnumerable`1 bookingSlots) in 
>   C:\dev\ZBooking.Client\core\ZBookings.Services\BookingService.cs:line 79\r\n\r\n
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: \r\n   at ZBookings.BookingService.<>c_*DisplayClass9`1.b*_5(BookingSlot p) in 
>   C:\dev\ZBookings\core\ZBookings.Services\BookingService.cs:line 79\r\n
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.All[TSource](IEnumerable'1 source, Func'2 predicate)\r\n
>
> at ZBookings.BookingService.MoveBooking[TBookingType](Int32 bookingId, IEnumerable`1 bookingSlots) in 
>   C:\dev\ZBookings\core\ZBookings.Services\BookingService.cs:line 79"

However, when this is displayed by the standard ASP.NET yellow screen it is:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      ZBooking.ApplicationServices.MethodMarshaller.Invoke(Delegate del, ZipIdentity zipIdentity, Object[] args) in C:\dev\ZBooking\core\ZBooking.ApplicationServices\MethodMarshaller.cs:147
>      ZBooking.ApplicationServices.MethodMarshaller.Invoke(Delegate del, ZipIdentity zipIdentity, Object[] args) in C:\dev\ZBooking\core\ZBooking.ApplicationServices\MethodMarshaller.cs:105
>      ZBooking.ApplicationServices.MethodMarshaller.Call(Func'3 del, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, ZipIdentity zipIdentity) in C:\dev\ZBooking\core\ZBooking.ApplicationServices\MethodMarshaller.cs:72
>   ...etc.

Calling `Server.GetLastError();` on Application_Error in Global.asax shows the correct stack trace. Where is the yellow screen stack trace coming from?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a secondary exception that "covers" the first one? The two exceptions seem to be too much different. Can you put a breakpoint at line 147 of MethodMarshaler? (and 105 and 72) and see what happens? And perhaps you could try to make the debugger stop to all the NullReferenceException .

Comment: That's kind of the point. One exception is covering the other - I am re-throwing the correct inner exception and then rewriting its stack trace from there. The stack trace re-write works but doesn't appear to bubble up to the YSOD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASP.NET's yellow screen of death gets the stack trace by constructing a [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) from the exception. It does this using the [`StackTrace(Exception, Boolean)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsay49kt.aspx) constructor. It then dumps the stack by walking the [StackFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx) objects supplied by the [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) object. It does not use the [`Exception.StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx) property.

Comment: That sounds promising. It appears to boil down to the `internal static extern void GetStackFramesInternal(StackFrameHelper sfh, int iSkip, Exception e);` call - I'll have a look at the SSCLI to see what method it invokes.

Comment: Meanwhile, I think the question, “Where is the yellow screen stack trace coming from?” has been answered. ;) Rest of your mileage, I'm afraid, may be longer.